# how to access the image captured using takePicture

Tags: xcode, camera

With takePicture, the camera captures an image (click), however I it does not call the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method. So how do we access the image?

Answer (score 1):

Did you register as the delegate for the picker?  Does your class implement UIImagePickerControllerDelegate?  If you do both of these things the code should work.  There are countless examples of this in the Apple documentation.